# How to add a common button for different jquery div functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a user defined progress bar for play different videos in html using jquery. I have to create same next, previous, play button for all videos. Each videos containing in a div. Each div containing some kind of css animations. Whenever we playing each videos, all animations should have to work. If anyone made this project before please Help.

```js
$(".wrapper-all .wrapper-inner .content2 .content-inner-wrapper .content2-inner button").click(function() {
  $(".videoo1").get(0).pause();
  $(".wrapper-all .wrapper-inner .content2").hide();
  $(".wrapper-all .wrapper-inner .content3").show();
  $(".videoo2").get(0).play();
  $(".wrapper-all .wrapper-inner .content3 .content-inner-wrapper").show();
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#c3-anim1").addClass("slide-in-right");
  }, 4000);
});
```

Comment: Please add the HTML code as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am unsure if it will work but instead of creating different button you can create an eventListner on div class.
Generate random ID when click any button and bind that ID to the current div.
With that ID you can access and control the buttons i.e play,pause,next etc. for that video.
You can remove the ID attribute if clicked on some other video or can check if ID is available use it else generate a new one.
I hope this will give you some idea if not solve your problem.Thanks!